# my recent questions display

Tags: feature-request

to view my recent questions, I have to do 2-3 clicks and there are 2-3 page redirects involved.

1. select my profile
2. click on questions tab
3. sort by newest

Is there any other short-cut way of accessing self posted questions that I am not aware of? with single click, like comments?

If not, I would like to suggest showing of my own recently posted questions in recent inbox messages, or wherever it would make sense.

Comment: Would using a browser bookmark be acceptable, for example you could use: http://meta.stackexchange.com/users/274145/harishr?tab=questions&sort=newest

Comment: What is the recent comments dropdown? I am not familiar with it.

Comment: @Oded recent inbox messages, where your see the updates of recently posted comments / answers

Comment: @PeterJ I use multiple stackoverflow sites, it would be pain to do it for all the sites, but yehh that is an acceptable work-around

Comment: That's an inbox - items directed at you, not ones that have originated with you. Your profile page should list recent posts when you click it (as well as other information).

Comment: i search a rare word of my question and it appears in the search result.
An easy to reach menu entry would be wellcome !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can bookmark this URL and get to it in one single click:
https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3Ame+is%3Aquestion&tab=newest

This is using the advanced search operators `user:me` and `is:question`, then selecting the "newest" tab to sort by newest questions first.

Answer (score 1):

There is no *built in* way to do that; however, it is possible to make a userscript that does so, like this:

```
var profileLink = $(".topbar .topbar-links .profile-me");
profileLink.css("margin-right", "0px");
profileLink.after('<a href="/users/current?tab=questions&sort=newest" class="profile-me" style="vertical-align: top; padding-top: 10px; height: 24px">Q</a>');
```